# Replace PowerPoint charts with identical charts

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

So I'm having an issue where I can't send a presentation over to a client because the files I'm sending are too big and are getting blocked by their firewall. I've pinned it down to the charts in my presentation being too big ~250kB each, and I have around 100 charts in a presentation. So this can bloat the file size up pretty quickly. Furthermore, I believe this is because the charts were copied from other presentations and then edited in this one which makes them embedded charts. The solution I've found is that if I create a new chart and then copy all the formatting over, the charts now are reduced to their average ~5-15kb sizes, but doing this by hand for every project and for every chart would take ages.

What I need: I'm looking to create a quick macro that will go through all my charts, copy their formatting, their data, then delete them and create new charts that are identical in formatting and data, but smaller in bytes.

I'm having trouble thinking through how this would be achievable. Would I need to have the code read each every aspect of the chart individually, save it to variables then set everything one by one in the new chart or is there some way to automatically copy all the formatting from one chart to the next? If I have to do everything one at a time, what should be some things to look out for? Anything else to add, perhaps this isn't the best way or something else?
Some "pseudo-code" ideas for how to accomplish this effectively and quickly would be greatly appreciated.

One caveat is that it cannot simply be copied then pasted as a picture, the charts must retain their animation abilities by series.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a rather long solution which you possibly should pay for. You don't get the solution for free here. However, do you really need a macro here, what about OleObjects or embedded charts? have you tried on SuperUser site if anyone could suggest something?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I'm really not familiar with what OleObjects are and embedded charts just wouldn't work for me. Also, how is SuperUser different from stackoverflow?